# How to install GRUB on an external HDD

Tags: debian, grub, external-hdd

I have an HDD with two partitions, one for files and photos (`NTFS`) and one for a Debian

Is it possible to install `GRUB` somewhere on this drive so that I can plug it in any computer have the choice to boot on the Debian?

At the moment I can only boot on the Debian If I plug the HDD on the computer where I installed it